# How to add a logo to a captured image?

Tags: c#, unity, textures

I have a plane which contain a `WebCamTexture` and a button to capture the image 
[image]

script to capture the image

```
void CaptureAndSave () {
    Debug.Log (Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture);
    Texture2D snap = new Texture2D(Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.width, Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.height);
    snap.SetPixels(Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.GetPixels());
    snap.Apply();
    Debug.Log (Application.persistentDataPath.ToString());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(
        Application.persistentDataPath+"/my_image.png",
        snap.EncodeToPNG()
        );
}
```

[image]

this is the resulted image

how can i modify my code to add `the image` logo to my resulted picture ? so the captured image would look like this :

[image]

**EDIT:**
i tried to do a code to change the pixels in the of the webcameTexture like this :

```
public static Texture2D CombineTextures(GameObject obj, Texture2D background, Texture2D TodrawLogo)
{
    Vector3 v = obj.transform.position;// obj is TodrawLogo gameobject
    int width = TodrawLogo.width;
    int height = TodrawLogo.height;
    for (int x =(int)v.x; x < width; x++){
        background.SetPixel(x,(int)v.y,TodrawLogo.GetPixel(x,(int)v.y));
    }
    background.Apply();
    return background;
}
```

but i am out of luck also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes for your `CombineTextures` method,

```
public static Texture2D CombineTexture(GameObject obj, Texture2D background, Texture2D TodrawLogo)
{
    int width = TodrawLogo.width;
    int height = TodrawLogo.height;

    int backWidth = background.width;
    int backHeight = background.height;
    // bottom right corner
    int startX = backWidth - width;
    int startY = backHeight - height;
    // create new texture
    Texture2D t = new Texture2D(backWidth,backHeight);
    // right corner
    int y = 0;
    while (y < backHeight) {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < backWidth) {
            // set normal pixels
            background.SetPixel(x,y,background.GetPixel(x,y));
            // if we are at bottom right apply logo 
            //TODO also check alpha, if there is no alpha apply it!
            if(x >= startX && y < backHeight- startY)
                background.SetPixel(x,y,TodrawLogo.GetPixel(x-startX,y-startY));
            ++x;
        }
        ++y;
    }
    background.Apply();
    return background;
}
```

You can change the values inside while loop to place your texture where you want.

Comment: You can get rid of the `obj` parameter as well since it does not seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that effect by using a **Second Camera**.

Assuming that your Main Camera has `Depth` -1, add a second camera with `Depth` 0. Doing this will make the Second Camera render after the first.

You can then apply a specific layer [Layer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) to your *watermark* object and then configure your Second Camera (`Culling Mask` property) to render only the *watermark*.

This way you will have your Main Camera render the whole scene, while the Second Camera will render only the watermark object, on top of what the Main Camera outputs.

As for the capturing part, try take a [screenshot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html):

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown() {
        Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my edit please, my problem is not how i have to render the camera ,my problem is how should i save the watermark and the webcamtexture

Comment: My answer still stands.

Comment: but your answer is missing my point , the rendering is not the problem , the saving is the problem , as u can see i can save the captured image but without the watermark i need the final image to be the captured and on top of it the watermark as the image 3 show

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have you tried `Application.CaptureScreenshot`?

Comment: no i didn't because Application.CaptureScreenshot will make a screenshot for the whole view and by that the setting buttons and everything will be visible not online the camtexture and the watermark

Comment: You could easily crop it.

Comment: seriously man :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version which uses `Color32` rather than Color so we can utilize more integer math.  My watermark was done in PNG which uses integers only.  I also created an array of floats to prevent any floating point arithmetic when applying the watermark.  And I used a premature optimization technique of going backwards in a loop but that's just my habit.  This also handles transparency from an alpha channel.

```
// Initialize transparency map.  You can have this in a utility class
// if preferred
private static float[] TRANSPARENCY_MAP;

static MyClass() {
  TRANSPARENCY_MAP = new float[256];
  for (var i = 255 ; i >= 0; --i) {
    TRANSPARENCY_MAP[i] = (float)i/255;
  }
}

void AddWatermark(Texture2D target, Texture2D watermark) {
  // If your watermark is going to be reused a lot you may want to
  // store the GetPixels(), width and height as class variables.
  var watermarkPixels = watermark.GetPixels32();

  var pix = target.GetPixels32();

  for (var y = watermark.height - 1; y >= 0; --y) {
    for (var x = watermark.width - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
      var originInPix = 
        (y * target.width) + (target.width - watermark.width);
      var p1 = originInPix + x;
      var p2 = y * watermarkTexture.width + x;
      // Guard condition in case the watermark is larger than the image.
      if (p1 >= pix.Length || p2 >= watermarkPixels.Length)
      {
        continue;
      }
      var a = pix[p1];
      var b = watermarkPixels[p2];
      float l = TRANSPARENCY_MAP[b.a];
      pix[originInPix + x] = Color32.Lerp(a, b, l);
    }
  }
  target.SetPixels32(pix);
}
```